# Chrome browser related issue

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

this is our company web site and when we visit few pages in Chrome then a glitch is coming.i am not being able to understand how to fix it. this is bit css related issue i guess.

here is our page link http://www.bba-reman.com/pl/enquiry-pl.aspx 
please visit this page with chrome and then at the upper top side you will notice a small icon like things is coming. please help me how to fix it for chrome.

here also i am going to upload a picture of that glitch
[image]

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
<div class="knowledgebaseCarouselwrapper">
    <img src="images/knowledgebase-header-image2dyna.jpg" style="display: block;">
    <img src="images/knowledgebase-header-image3dyna.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="images/knowledgebase-header-image1dyna.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

There is no image on `http://www.bba-reman.com/pl/images/knowledgebase-header-image3dyna.jpg`.

[image]

Change it to:

```
<div class="knowledgebaseCarouselwrapper">
    <img src="../images/knowledgebase-header-image2dyna.jpg" style="display: block;">
    <img src="../images/knowledgebase-header-image3dyna.jpg" style="display: none;">
    <img src="../images/knowledgebase-header-image1dyna.jpg" style="display: none;">
</div>
```

It will point to `http://www.bba-reman.com/images/knowledgebase-header-image3dyna.jpg`, which is where image is actually available.

Comment: i never use chrome. so how can i use page inspector in chrome to select any portion of page. i saw chrome page inspector is not friendly like firefox. is there any firefox like page inspector available for chrome. thanks for the answer & help.

Comment: Looks like it's just a matter of personal preferences, because I think chrome dev tools are much better then firefox+firebug :)

Answer (score 1):

Change the image url from:

```
http://www.bba-reman.com/pl/images/knowledgebase-header-image1dyna.jpg
http://www.bba-reman.com/pl/images/knowledgebase-header-image2dyna.jpg
http://www.bba-reman.com/pl/images/knowledgebase-header-image3dyna.jpg
```

to:

```
http://www.bba-reman.com/images/knowledgebase-header-image1dyna.jpg
http://www.bba-reman.com/images/knowledgebase-header-image2dyna.jpg
http://www.bba-reman.com/images/knowledgebase-header-image3dyna.jpg
```

Comment: i never use chrome. so how can i use page inspector in chrome to select any portion of page. i saw chrome page inspector is not friendly like firefox. is there any firefox like page inspector available for chrome. thanks for the answer & help.

Comment: Right click on the element and choose _"inspect element"_. There you'll se the selected element and if there is some error, to to the **console tab** to see the error.